# Friend и namespace

Tags: функции, namespace, классы, c++

Доброго времени суток
Как здесь у класса ns::CL объявить дружественную функцию fnc, которая находится во внешнем global namespace?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace ns{
class CL
{
    int i;
public:
    friend void fnc();
};
};

void fnc()
{
    ns::CL cl;
    cout<<(cl.i=8)<<endl;  //ошибка
}

int main()
{
    fnc();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Необходимо поместить объявление функции до объявления класса.
В Вашем случае, на момент объявления класса функция просто не объявлена.

После критики добавляю код:
    void fnc();

```
namespace ns{
        class CL
    {
        int i;
    public:
    friend void ::fnc();
    };
};

void fnc()
{
ns::CL cl;
    cout<<(cl.i=8)<<endl;  //ошибка
}

int main()
{
    fnc();
}
```

Comment: код пробовали написать? не будет работать.

Comment: о том, что нужно использовать `::fnc();` в оригинальном ответе не упоминалось:)

Comment: это выяснилось уже при написании кода. :)

Answer (score 2):

Нашел решение
Нужно сделать предварительное объявление
void fnc();
и сделать
friend void ::fnc();

Comment: сори за дубляж.